# Coredata _clearRawPropertiesWithHint crash ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios9

I have been stuck with this crash for few days and seem to be going nowhere.

```
Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x14f016920
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

Thread : Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x14f016920
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019953dbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184969c84 __CFBasicHashDrain + 276
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184814da4 CFRelease + 256
3  CoreData                       0x0000000184632cf0 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet dealloc] + 68
4  CoreData                       0x00000001845f8d3c -[_CDSnapshot dealloc] + 84
5  CoreData                       0x00000001846068e0 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _clearRawPropertiesWithHint:] + 388
6  CoreData                       0x00000001846066bc -[NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:] + 448
7  CoreData                       0x0000000184603e10 -[NSManagedObject dealloc] + 104
8  CoreData                       0x0000000184603428 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1076
9  CoreData                       0x0000000184681678 __89-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _registerAyncReferenceCallback]_block_invoke + 104
10 CoreData                       0x000000018467bc20 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 196
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199d25770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199d3175c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199d29274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199d25770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199d33bb0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199d3334c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000199f39478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
```

Any pointers on how I can debug this crash? The same didn't crash in iOS 8. Could it be a iOS 9 crash and hopefully it will be fixed in the subsequent iOS versions?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post the block of code that is generating the crash. Looks like something is getting dealloc'd prematurely, it may be in your code or it might a bug in the framework in which case you will have to file a radar.

Comment: Did you find an explanation to this bug Neelesh?